# Java debugging - How to disable logging and print runtime errors

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I just ran into an error with my code and it says to reference the Glassfish log.  Is there a way that I can turn off logging so it'll just show me the errors in runtime?

Comment: Consider tagging with "glassfish".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the GlassFish logging levels in the GlassFish administration console. Exact location of the log level configuration page in the GF admin console may slightly vary based on the GlassFish version you use.